# Error with select function from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

When I use the select function from dplyr, it doesn't work and gives me an error stating that the column names that I want to select are unused arguments. However, if I specify dplyr before the function call like s: "dplyr::select" then it works as normal:

Here is a sample df:

```
 sampledf <- structure(list(CRN = c(5497L, 6515L, 7248L, 36956L, 37021L), 
        varA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
        "B"), class = "factor"), varB = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), VarC = c(NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, 2L), varD = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), varE = c(1L, 1L, 4L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("CRN", 
        "varA", "varB", "varC", "varD", "varE"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

this produces the error:

```
 sample_error <- select(sampledf, varA)
```

> Error in select(sampledf, varA) : unused argument (varA)

and this works:

```
 sample_working <- dplyr::select(sampledf, varA)

 version
```

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          4.0
>   year           2017
>   month          04
>   day            21
>   svn rev        72570
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
>   nickname       You Stupid Darkness

And here is the session info:

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>    [1] readxl_1.0.0    bindrcpp_0.2    doBy_4.5-15     reshape2_1.4.2  ltm_1.0-0       > polycor_0.7-9   msm_1.6.4
>    [8] MASS_7.3-47     glmnet_2.0-10   foreach_1.4.3   Matrix_1.2-9    caret_6.0-76    lattice_0.20-35 dplyr_0.7.2
>   [15] purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.6.3     tibble_1.3.3    > > > > > > ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1 openxlsx_4.0.17
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] Rcpp_0.12.11       lubridate_1.6.0    mvtnorm_1.0-6      assertthat_0.2.0   > psych_1.7.5        R6_2.2.2
>    [7] cellranger_1.1.0   plyr_1.8.4         MatrixModels_0.4-1 stats4_3.4.0       > httr_1.3.1         rlang_0.1.1
>   [13] lazyeval_0.2.0     minqa_1.2.4        SparseM_1.77       car_2.1-4          > nloptr_1.0.4       labeling_0.3
>   [19] splines_3.4.0      lme4_1.1-13        stringr_1.2.0      foreign_0.8-67     munsell_0.4.3      broom_0.4.2
>   [25] compiler_3.4.0     modelr_0.1.1       pkgconfig_2.0.1    mnormt_1.5-5       mgcv_1.8-17        nnet_7.3-12
>   [31] expm_0.999-2       codetools_0.2-15   ModelMetrics_1.1.0 grid_3.4.0         nlme_3.1-131       jsonlite_1.5
>   [37] gtable_0.2.0       magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.1       stringi_1.1.5      xml2_1.1.1         iterators_1.0.8
>   [43] tools_3.4.0        forcats_0.2.0      glue_1.1.0         hms_0.3            survival_2.41-3    parallel_3.4.0
>   [49] pbkrtest_0.4-7     colorspace_1.3-2   rvest_0.3.2        bindr_0.1          haven_1.1.0        quantreg_5.33

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Either you overwrite the dplyr `select()` function with your own function or you loaded a package after dplyr that has it's own `select()` function that's taking precedence. Run `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` to see where the function is doubly defined. Maybe show `sessionInfo()` we can see what other packages you have loaded.

Comment: Sounds like a name clash with `MASS::select`. Loading dplyr after MASS will fix it.

Comment: sessionInfo() is included as requested

Comment: The packages MASS does have a `select` function as suggested. However, i don't actually explicitly install it. Do i need it for something?

Comment: @stevezissou Installation isn’t the issue. Loading is. If you didn’t load it manually, the ‹ltm› package appears to be doing it. [Complain to its maintainer](https://github.com/drizopoulos/ltm/issues/new), or don’t use that (the ltm package also attaches two other packages; ugh).

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and it was caused by name clash with another package. Use: `dplyr::select` to specify the package.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but just to fill the information from the comments into an actual answer:

This is indeed caused by a name clash with another package; 99(.9?)% of the time the particular package at "fault" will be the `MASS` package, which has a (poorly documented) `select()` function (which is intended for extracting the optimal penalization parameter for a ridge regression).

In general, to diagnose this problem, `find("select")` will find where the `select` function is actually found first on the search path.

Possibly solutions:

- avoid loading the `MASS` package after the `dplyr` (or `tidyverse`) packages.
- as in @EJAg's answer, specify `dplyr::select()` when calling the function.
- assign in your global workspace: `select <- dplyr::select` (see also the `conflicted` package).