# Error with dplyr functions requiring dplyr:: prefix even when package is loaded

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(starts_with("a"))
```

Throws an error:

```
Error in select(., starts_with("special_int")) : 
  unused argument (starts_with("special_int"))
```

The error resolves when I specify dplyr in front of the function, as in ```dplyr::select()``

Does anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with select function from dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325145/error-with-select-function-from-dplyr)

Comment: What does `environment(select)` return? That might give you a clue where the conflicting `select` function is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `select` function occurs in different packages and this could mask the `dplyr::select` if those packages are loaded after `dplyr`.  When we specify the `::`, then it gets the correct function.  So either,

```
df %>%
   dplyr::select(starts_with("a"))
```

Or create a new name and call it

```
dpselect <- dplyr::select
df %>%
   dpselect(starts_with("a"))
```

---

In `base R`, we can find the functions that have some [`conflicts`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/conflicts)

```
conflicts()
```